# NSDictionary: Store 3 float values for every key

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

how can I do this? Basically I want to store RGB color values that can be retrieved in response to a color name. My C++ code uses boost unordered_map to do this:

```
("SlateBlue1", Color(0.5137f, 0.4353f,1.0f)) 
("tan3", Color(0.8039f, 0.5216f, 0.2471f)) 
("grey32", Color(0.3216f, 0.3216f, 0.3216f))
```

Color is a class that stores the 3 values.
Trying to do this in Objective-C is tying me up in knots and weird errors! Most of the dictionary examples I've found are simply matching 2 strings. Of course I can just use the C++ code in a .mm file, but if anyone has any ideas how to achieve this the Obj-C way, I'd be pleased to learn, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same in Cocoa - use a NSDictionary instead of the unordered_map, NSString instead of const char* for the key and UIColor instead of Color for the object and you're done.

E.g., `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [UIColor redColor] forKey: @"Red"]]` to create a single-entry map. Adjust for multiple colors and you're all set. Use NSColor if you're not on iOS.

You might be missing the key point that a dictionary is an (almost) untyped collection, so it can store a heterogenous set of object types using a heterogenous set of key types.

Answer (score 0):

If you're color object extends NSObject, you should be able to store those colors as the values in your `NSDictionary`.

```
NSDictionary *colors = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:Color1, @"SlateBlue1", Color2, @"tan3", Color3, @"grey32", nil ];
```

That should work and then you'd use

```
Color *mycolor = [colors objectForKey:@"SlateBlue1"];
```

And then access your colors from your object.

Also, not sure of the purpose of your color object but you could use `NSColor` for Cocoa or `UIColor` for Cocoa-touch to store these as well.

(I haven't tested this code, just wrote from memory)

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks, how do I avoid leaking all the Color objects that get created for the dictionary, are they copied into there? Do they get destroyed when the dictionary does, or should they be deallocated separately?

Comment: If you use one of the UIColor class methods, like `[UIColor redColor]` or `[UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.2 blue:.7 alpha:1]`, you don't have to worry about leaking them. You don't get an "owning" reference so you don't have to release it, and the NSDictionary will retain and release it when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `UIColor` object or similar, the other answers cover it.  If you really want to store three floats, you have a couple of options.  You can store an NSArray of three NSNumbers for each triple of floats:

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.7], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.2], nil], @"bleem",
    ... // more array/string pairs
    nil];
```

Or you can use an `NSData` for each triple of floats:

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSData dataWithBytes:&(float[]){ .5, .7, .2} length:3*sizeof(float)], @"bleem",
    ... // more data/string pairs
    nil];
```